# Roles and permissions API Rest - Lack of permissions of other modules to complete a flow in the frontend

Tags: rest, spring-security, frontend, user-permissions, user-roles

I have a problem related to security (roles and permissions), I have been investigating (a couple of days) and I can not find a solution, I hope you can guide me to find alternatives.

#### CONTEXT

I am developing a **Rest API with Spring Boot** and the **frontend with NuxtJS (VueJS)**. I have configured the **Spring Security module** and have chosen to use a **security strategy based on roles and permissions**:

- Users can only have a single role.
- And each role can be assigned one or many permissions (the role helps me to group the permissions).
- I think it is not too much to say that obviously several users can have the same role.

For example the **user jhon** is assigned the role of **ROL_INVOICE**. And this role is assigned the following permissions:

- CREATE_INVOICE
- READ_DETAIL_INVOICE
- READ_ALL_INVOICE
- UPDATE_INVOICE
- DELETE_INVOICE

As you can see, the **user jhon** only has access to the **invoice module within the application**.

#### THE PROBLEM

When the **user jhon** accesses the **View create invoice** on the frontend, he will have the possibility to search for products to be able to add them to the invoice detail, so I need to make the following request:

```js
async filterProducts(){
    let products = await this.$axios.get("/products?search=nameProduct:guitars")
    .then((response) => { return response.data; });

    // other code...
}
```

The problem happens in this step, since I cannot retrieve the products, because the **user jhon** does not have the **READ_ALL_PRODUCTS** permission , since the endpoint validates the user's permissions:

```java
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @GetMapping("/productos")
    @PostAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ_ALL_PRODUCTS')")
    public List<Productos> readAll(@RequestParam String search) {
        // code impl...
    }

    // other enpoints code...
}
```

#### WHAT I HAVE UP TO THE MOMENT

- Obviously I cannot add the **READ_ALL_PRODUCTS** permission to the **ROL_INVOICE** since this would allow **user jhon** to have access to the **View all products** view (in the frontend views the user's permissions are also validated to determine if they are granted access or not). which is not viable because it goes against business rules.
- I had also considered modifying the endpoint security as follows:

```java
@RestController
public class ProductController {
    @GetMapping("/productos")
    @PostAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ_ALL_PRODUCTS', 'CREATE_INVOICE')")
    public List<Productos> readAll(@RequestParam String search) {
        // code impl...
    }

    // other enpoints code...
}
```

But I consider that it is not still the best solution, I consider that the problem of recovering the products is not a problem for the user, but rather a frontend problem (it is the responsibility of the frontend to present the data correctly)

---

How can I address this problem? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions

Comment: It's not clear to me why you don't want to grant to user the `READ_ALL_PRODUCTS` authority. Since they are allowed to read all the products, then they should have the `READ_ALL_PRODUCTS` authority. If there is a different endpoint that they should not access, then you should create a different authority for that endpoint.

Comment: @eleftheria for now I have chosen to leave the endpoint noted as follows
```@PostAuthorize("hasAuthority('READ_ALL_PRODUCTS', 'CREATE_INVOICE')")
```
With which I can guarantee that the user jhon:

1. CANNOT access the next screen "/frontend/products" 

2. If can access the following screen "/frontend/invoice" when adding products to the invoice, I make the request to the API and I can retrieve the products thanks to the fact that I have the CREATE_INVOICE permission. It is worth mentioning that jhon can only view the productName and the productPrice